# JavaScript If Statement Not Comparing Variables Correctly

Tags: javascript

I am making a rock paper scissors game. I have a function that checks if a player has won yet. On the home screen, there was an input that allowed you to select how many wins you need. When someone's score equals it, the game should end. However, nothing happens when the function is called. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```js
// Variables
const play = document.getElementById("play");

const homepage = document.getElementById("homepage");
const gamepage = document.getElementById("gamepage");
const victoryScreen = document.getElementById("victory-screen");
const defeatScreen = document.getElementById("defeat-screen");

const firstToInput = document.getElementById("first-to-input");
const firstTo = document.getElementById("first-to");

const userNameInput = document.getElementById("username-input");
const userName = document.getElementById("username");
const cpuNameInput = document.getElementById("cpu-name-input");
const cpuName = document.getElementById("cpu-name");

const userScore = document.getElementById("user-score");
const cpuScore = document.getElementById("cpu-score");

const rock = document.getElementById("rock");
const paper = document.getElementById("paper");
const scissors = document.getElementById("scissors");

const cpuMessage = document.getElementById("cpu-message");
const resultMessage = document.getElementById("result");

// Shows username and CPU name at top of gamepage
function names() {
    if (userNameInput.value === "") {
        userNameInput.value = "You";
    };
    if (cpuNameInput.value === "") {
        cpuNameInput.value = "CPU";
    };
    userName.textContent = userNameInput.value;
    cpuName.textContent = cpuNameInput.value;
}

// Randomly generates CPU choice
function getCpuChoice() {
    const cpuChoice = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    cpuMessage.textContent = `${cpuName.textContent} chose ${cpuChoice[random]}`;
    return cpuChoice[random];
}

// Adds score to user and displays win message
function winRound() {
    userScore.textContent++;
    resultMessage.textContent = "You Win!"
}

// Adds score to CPU and dislays loss message
function loseRound() {
    cpuScore.textContent++;
    resultMessage.textContent = "You Lose!"
}

// Displays tie message
function tieRound() {
    resultMessage.textContent = "Tie!"
}

// Determines winner
function result(userChoice) {
    const cpuSelection = getCpuChoice();
    switch (`${userChoice}-${cpuSelection}`) {
        case "rock-scissors":
        case "paper-rock":
        case "scissors-paper":
            winRound();
            break;
        case "rock-paper":
        case "paper-scissors":
        case "scissors-rock":
            loseRound();
            break;
        case "rock-rock":
        case "paper-paper":
        case "scissors-scissors":
            tieRound();
            break;
    }
}

// Main game loop
function gameLoop() {
    checkScore();

    // Defines user choice
    rock.addEventListener("click", () => {
        result("rock");
    })
    paper.addEventListener("click", () => {
        result("paper");
    })
    scissors.addEventListener("click", () => {
        result("scissors");
    })
}

// Checks if someone has won
function checkScore() {
    if (userScore.textContent == firstToInput.value) {
        console.log("win")
        gamepage.style.display = "none";
        victoryScreen.style.display = "block";
    }
    if (cpuScore.textContent == firstToInput.value) {
        console.log("lose")
        gamepage.style.display = "none";
        defeatScreen.style.display = "block";
    }
}

// Starts game
play.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // Moves from homepage to gamepage
    homepage.style.display = "none";
    gamepage.style.display = "block";

    // Displays how many wins you need
    firstTo.textContent = `First to ${firstToInput.value}`;

    names();
    gameLoop();
})
```

```css
#gamepage {
  display: none;
}

#victory-screen {
  display: none;
}

#defeat-screen {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Homepage -->
    <div id="homepage">
        <h1 id="homepage-title">ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS</h1>
        <div>
            <img class="icons" src="images/rock.png" title='&lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com/icons/set/hand-rock">Hand Rock icon&lt;/a> icon by &lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com">Icons8&lt;/a>' alt="rock icon">
            <img class="icons" src="images/paper.png" title='&lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com/icons/set/hand-paper">Hand Paper icon&lt;/a> icon by &lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com">Icons8&lt;/a>' alt="paper icon">
            <img class="icons" src="images/scissors.png" title='&lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com/icons/set/hand-scissors">Hand Scissors icon&lt;/a> icon by &lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com">Icons8&lt;/a>' alt="scissors icon">
        </div>
        <label id="first-to-input-label" for="first-to-input">First to...</label>
        <br>
        <input id="first-to-input" type="number" min="1">
        <br>
        <input id="username-input" class="names" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username">
        <input id="cpu-name-input" class="names" type="text" placeholder="Enter CPU Name">
        <br>
        <button id="play">Play</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Gamepage -->
    <div id="gamepage">
        <h2 id="first-to"></h2>
        <h2 id="names-scores">
            <span id="username"></span>
            -
            <span id="user-score">0</span>
            :
            <span id="cpu-score">0</span>
            -
            <span id="cpu-name"></span>
        </h2>
        <h1 id="gamepage-title">SELECT AN OPTION</h1>
        <div id="options">
            <img id="rock" class="options" src="images/rock.png" title='&lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com/icons/set/hand-rock">Hand Rock icon&lt;/a> icon by &lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com">Icons8&lt;/a>' alt="rock icon">
            <img id="paper" class="options" src="images/paper.png" title='&lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com/icons/set/hand-paper">Hand Paper icon&lt;/a> icon by &lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com">Icons8&lt;/a>' alt="paper icon">
            <img id="scissors" class="options" src="images/scissors.png" title='&lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com/icons/set/hand-scissors">Hand Scissors icon&lt;/a> icon by &lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com">Icons8&lt;/a>' alt="scissors icon">
        </div>
        <h3 id="cpu-message"></h3>
        <h3 id="result"></h3>
    </div>
    <!-- Victory Screen -->
    <div id="victory-screen">
        <h1 id="victory-message">VICTORY</h1>
        <button class="replay">Replay</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Defeat Screen -->
    <div id="defeat-screen">
        <h1 id="defeat-message">DEFEAT</h1>
        <button class="replay">Replay</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Nobody but you knows what `userScore` or `firstToInput` mean.

Comment: Are there any messages in the console? Can you show the code where you hook up the event listener on the input?

Comment: Can u add more context, how is userscore, cpuscore, and firstToInput variable looks like?

Comment: @Pointy I believe they are HTML element references to some input elements, as I can see `textContent` and `value` properties

Comment: @KunalMukherjee sure, but it's not posted as part of the question. Without knowing how those variables are set, it's impossible to give accurate assistance.

Comment: Your edit is a step in the right direction but you still need to add more code for this to be solvable -- please read the following support centre article for guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Where is `gameLoop()` called? If it is not called somewhere, then those event listeners aren't being added, and that'll be the cause of your problem.

Comment: It's called when you click "play". I just added it to the question

Comment: So `checkScore()` is only going to be called once then, when you click "Play". Your "game loop" isn't looping so to speak, it's only running the once -- not that I think you actually need a loop here. Can you show the `result()` function? Perhaps that calls `checkScore()`? Do the messages get printed to the console if you click "Play" after making a move?

Comment: @Toastrackenigma So should I use a for loop that runs until someone wins?

Comment: OK, so the issue is that you're never calling `checkScore()` in a meaningful place. Remove the `checkScore()` call from `gameLoop()`, and add it to the bottom of `result()` instead. I've started the re-opeing process now you've got enough details, but I think that should resolve your problem anyway. You don't need a loop.

Comment: Awesome! it works! Sorry about the bad question. I'll be more descriptive next time.

Comment: No worries man, I'm glad to hear that it works! Have a great night :)

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function `checkScore();` into the `result` function rather than `gameLoop`

```
// Determines winner
function result(userChoice) {
    const cpuSelection = getCpuChoice();
    switch (`${userChoice}-${cpuSelection}`) {
        case "rock-scissors":
        case "paper-rock":
        case "scissors-paper":
            winRound();
            break;
        case "rock-paper":
        case "paper-scissors":
        case "scissors-rock":
            loseRound();
            break;
        case "rock-rock":
        case "paper-paper":
        case "scissors-scissors":
            tieRound();
            break;
    }
    checkScore();
}
```